# React Ag Grid frameworkComponents doesnt rerenders when param changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working with React Ag-Grid. 
I am trying to calculate a column Sum and show it in a status bar

It looks like this:
[image]

my component is really simple:

```
import React from "react";

const AgGridSumComponent = ({sum, sumName}) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div style={{marginTop: '9px'}}>
                <span className="component">
                    Total {sumName + ' Sum: ' + sum}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AgGridSumComponent;
```

and its defined like this:

```
 render() {
        var columnDef = this.props.isCheckbox === true ? this.state.columnDefs : this.state.columnDefsChannel;
        var WrappedAgGridSumComponent = () => <AgGridSumComponent sum={this.state.totalSpendSum} sumName={'Spend'} />;
        var frameworkComponents= { statusBarComponent: WrappedAgGridSumComponent };
        return (
            <div
                id="myGrid"
                style={{
                    height: this.props.tableHeight,
                    width: "100%",
                }}
                className="ag-theme-balham"
            >
                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={columnDef}
                    rowData={this.props.rowData}
                    components={this.state.components}
                    getRowHeight={this.state.getRowHeight}
                    defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
                    rowSelection={this.state.rowSelection}
                    suppressRowClickSelection={true}
                    onSelectionChanged={this.props.onSelectionChanged.bind(this)}

                    onGridReady={this.onGridReady}

                    columnTypes={ this.state.columnTypes }

                    suppressAggFuncInHeader={true}
                    enableCellChangeFlash={true}
                    statusBar={this.state.statusBar}
                    frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
                />
            </div>
        );
```

when the Sum is calculated and stored in the aggrid component state (this.state.totalSpendSum) the aggrid is not re rendering the before sum, as shown in the picture the sum remains zero (which is the default state value before the rows where brought)

Comment: Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: I want to calculate the sum value of the ag-grid column. I am using a function that receives the sum value as props and then I Render that function into the ag-grid. the problem is when I calculate the column sum and update the props the aggrid is not re rendering the function with the new props.

Comment: They've added it in enterprise edition
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-status-bar/#grid-provided-status-bar-components
I've used imperative gridApi to dynamically insert/update a totals row.
If you want that I can share code